# "BDDMockito.given ( T methodCall ) [static] : BDDMockito.BDDMyOngoingStubbing<T> " its give error in my code

Tags: java

I install all Mokito jar files in my project and also import it in my project but sill its "BDDMockito.given ( T methodCall ) [static]  :  BDDMockito.BDDMyOngoingStubbing " its give error in my code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEliJ.png)

Comment: please suggest something to solve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it
just simply use BDDMockito.given and followed by the code so it works.